# Bigcommerce 500 error for some stores when listing orders

Tags: python, bigcommerce

**Problem description:**

We're importing orders from Bigcommerce stores by using the official Python wrapper. We ran into a couple of 500 errors lately. This happens randomly (as far as we can tell) - for most stores it works fine, for some it throws a 500 error. We're calling the **Bigcommerce list Orders resource** (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#list-orders).

**Sample code:**

Here's a manual test I just ran by directly hitting the REST API:

```
import requests
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': 'kbke.....', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Client': '168x.....'}
url = 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/zv.../v2/orders'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.status_code
500
r.content
'An error has occurred.'
```

Does anyone have tips on what would cause this 500 error? I've asked this Bigcommerce user to re-install our app but still receive the error.